# Tree structure data approval hierarchy query

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree

I have some tables, let's call them table `ApprovalHierarchy`

```
ID  GroupApp            ParentID
1   Project             NULL
2   Leader Mechanical   1
3   Engineer Mechanical 2
4   Leader Electrical   1
5   Engineer Electrical 4
```

And this is table `GroupMember`

```
ID GroupID  Username  Password
1   1        Frey      12345 
2   2        Anne      12345       
3   2        Bryan     12345
4   3        Belle     12345
5   3        Will      12345
6   4        Drio      12345
7   5        Maxio     12345
8   5        James     12345
```

`GroupID` is a column which contains id from table `ApprovalHierarchy`, for example `Username : Frey` have `GroupID : 1` that is Frey as `Project`

And I have one more table, let's call them table `Mailbox`, and in column `Approval` this is the output that I meant. I need to insert/update column `Approval`, if `FromUser` and also same with `Username` have `GroupID` and have `ParentID`, I want write that `Username` in column `Approval`, this is for example the output that I want in column `Approval`:

```
ID FromUser ToUser  Message  Approval
1  Belle    Client  Hello    Anne, Bryan
2  Anne     Client  Hai      Frey
3  Maxio    Client  Hii      Drio
4  Drio     Client  hey      Frey
```

This is for table `Mailbox`

This is the query in table `Mailbox` that I meant

```
CREATE TABLE Mailbox (
    ID INT
    ,FromUser NVARCHAR(100)
    ,ToUser NVARCHAR(100)
    ,Message NVARCHAR(100)
    ,Approver NVARCHAR(100)
    )
INSERT INTO dbo.Mailbox
VALUES
(1,'Belle','Client','Hello',' '),
(2, 'Anne', 'Client', 'Hai', ' '),
(3,  'Maxio', 'Client', 'Hii', ' '),
(4, 'Drio', 'Client' , 'hey', ' ')
```

---

```
ID FromUser ToUser  Message  Approval
1  Belle    Client  Hello    Group 2
2  Anne     Client  Hai      Group 1
3  Maxio    Client  Hii      Group 4
4  Drio     Client  hey      Group 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the query. [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2210533db0d3278766ecdd0f44783f7c) working code

```
SELECT a.ID
    ,a.[From User]
    ,a.[To User]
    ,a.Message
    ,ISNULL(SUBSTRING(a.Approver, 0, LEN(a.Approver)), 'No Approver Exists') [Approver]
FROM (
    SELECT Id
        ,Username [From User]
        ,'Client' [To User]
        ,'Hi' [Message]
        ,(
            SELECT gm.Username + ',' [text()]
            FROM dbo.ApprovalHierarchy ah
            JOIN dbo.GroupMember gm ON ah.ParentID = gm.GroupID
            WHERE ah.Id = gmm.GroupID
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') [Approver]
    FROM dbo.GroupMember gmm
    ) a
```

Update Query:

```
UPDATE m
SET m.Approver = ISNULL(SUBSTRING(a.Approver, 0, LEN(a.Approver)), 'No Approver Exists')
FROM (
    SELECT Id
        ,Username
        ,'Client' [To User]
        ,'Hi' [Message]
        ,(
            SELECT gm.Username + ', ' [text()]
            FROM dbo.ApprovalHierarchy ah
            JOIN dbo.GroupMember gm ON ah.ParentID = gm.GroupID
            WHERE ah.Id = gmm.GroupID
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') [Approver]
    FROM dbo.GroupMember gmm
    ) a
INNER JOIN dbo.Mailbox m ON a.Username = m.FromUser

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Mailbox
```

Update Query to update the Group {GroupId}

```
UPDATE m
SET m.Approver = IIF(a.Approver = 'Group ', 'No Approver Exists', a.Approver)
FROM (
    SELECT gmm.Id
        ,Username
        ,'Client' [To User]
        ,'Hi' [Message]
        ,'Group ' + CAST(ah.ParentId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) [Approver]
    FROM dbo.GroupMember gmm
    INNER JOIN dbo.ApprovalHierarchy ah ON gmm.GroupId = ah.Id
    ) a
INNER JOIN dbo.Mailbox m ON a.Username = m.FromUser
```

Select Results:

[image]

Results from Mailbox after update:

[image]
[image]

Comment: If your `sql-server` supports the `STRING_AGG`, you can use that

Comment: Thankyou for helping me, it's work:) Actually the output is in the column name table `Mailbox`. How to insert/update that in column `Approver`?

Comment: Can you update the question with your `Mailbox` table. or just give the columns in that table, we can join that table to this query and get the results

Comment: Do you want to update the `Approval` in the `Mailbox` table? What value should be updated in `Approval` column for user `Frey` who belongs to `ID: 1`

Comment: I've been update the question, please check my updated question..

Comment: If it is a direct insert you can give the values manually right?

Comment: I think for user Frey the output is NULL or something because they didn't need approval and because they are head of the group

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220362/discussion-between-sowmyadhar-gourishetty-and-dea-ananda).

Comment: Hello, can you check my message again in chat? Thankyou:)

Comment: updated the answer please check, also updated the DBFIDDLE link

Comment: Thankyou so much for helping me again!!:)